# regex for "finding whole word only" plus allowing one character

Tags: regex, vbscript

Hi I'm using this regular expression to find whole word only:
example:

```
Dim oRE, bMatch
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Pattern = "\bFunction\b"
bMatch = oRE.Test("Functions") 'return false
bMatch = oRE.Test("Function dummy") 'return true
```

I want to allow one character at the end of the string. The char i want to allow is the double quote ("). So i would like this line of code to return true:

```
bMatch = oRE.Test("Function"+chr(34)+" dummy") 'chr(34) is the charcode of doublequote (")
```

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a variable with `chr(34)` and concatenate it into your pattern.

```
dq = Chr(34)
oRE.Pattern = "\bFunction" & dq & "+\b"
```

Then you will be able to match the double quotes as well.

`+` for 1 or more double quotes after *Function* (modify it per your needs).

Answer (score 0):

The double quote can be written like this `\x22` in order to replace it easily in your pattern **`"`**

Hope that this what you want as result [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Frjaqz/1)

---

```
Dim oRE, bMatch
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Pattern = "\bFunction.+?\x22"
aMatch = oRE.Test("Functions""")
bMatch = oRE.Test("Function dummy""")
wscript.echo "Functions " & aMatch
wscript.echo "Functions dummy " & bMatch
```